# How do I access helpers I've written in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've written a helper for my user model in user_helper.rb

```
module UserHelper
  def get_array_of_names_and_user_ids
    User.all(&:first_name) + User.all.map(&:user_id)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately when I type in

```
 <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :assignee, "Assigned to" %>
        <%= select(:task, :assignee_id, User.get_array_of_names_and_user_ids )%>
  </div>
```

It can't see it. Where am I going wrong? I'm using devise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. The helper doesn't become a class method like that -- it becomes accessible as a method in your views.  Just simply call `get_array_of_names_and_user_ids`.

Answer (score 2):

Helpers are for views not for model.
For model you should define class methods in User model

```
class User
  def self.get_array_of_names_and_user_ids
    User.all(&:first_name) + User.all.map(&:user_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hand code this helper as Rails provides a helper called [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) for this purpose.

In your view simply add this:

```
<%= collection_select(:task, :assignee_id, User.all, :id, :first_name, 
   :prompt => true) %>
```

**Note:**

I am assuming you have a small set of users in your DB(<30). Otherwise, you have to use some other control to select users.

Answer (score 0):

Helpers are methods that can be called in the view, not methods to be called on the model
Just call get_array_of_names_and_user_ids